# "Consider" vs. "Regard"

Tags: difference, word-difference

> 1) We don't consider this film suitable for young children (LongMan)
>
> Could it be -- We don't regard this film as a suitable film for young children
>
> 2) She is considered to be one of the finest pianist of her generation
>
> Could it be -- She is widely regarded as the finest pianist of her generation
>
> 3) I am seriously considered resigning (it seems can't be written with regard)
>
> 4) She stood back and regarded him coldly

According to LongMan:

**Regard** is thinking about someone in a particular way.

**Consider** is to think about something carefully before making decision.

I wrote this paragraph:

> While such features can be used to classify the page elements into "content" and "noise", they may not be applicable to all elements of the page. To illustrate this, suppose we want to eliminate the navigation bar from the page sidebar. We may create a rule in which the link density is employed to distinguish such a part, but when this rule is applied to the page, all such elements are removed regardless of their locations in the page, even if they are within the main content (e.g. Table of Contents). However, if the user was able to specify the context in which a rule must be applied (e.g. the page sidebar), then before removing such an element, context would be **regarded**.

Could it be **considered** in replace of **regarded**? Are they the same?

---

However, sometimes in the articles I confuse them and need **a rule of thumb** for that. (Now, it seems **making decision** is a key)

Comment: Idiomatically, ***regarded*** is extremely unlikely in this exact context. Reasonable alternatives include ***considered, taken into consideration, taken into account***.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/consider-or-regard

Comment: @Sander: It's quite possible OP was driven to ask this question specifically because he's seen many definitions like that one. It glibly points out that ***regard*** is often used as a direct replacement for ***consider*** - but unless I'm much mistaken, it gives no insight into why that would *not* be appropriate in the specific example here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Sander, I made a rule that *consider* is used when a decision is going to be made

Comment: Rather curiously (you might think), the more "literal" synonym of ***to regard*** *(**to look at**)* can actually replace ***consider*** in some contexts where ***regard*** can't be used. For example, *I considered a Ford before deciding to buy a Mercedes* works fine with ***looked at***, but not ***regarded***. But your "rule" will probably stand you in good stead.

Answer (score 1):

Regard has the word consider in it's technical definition: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/regard

So it is easy to see why they might be viewed as interchangeable.

"Consider" has a general connotation that logical evidence is being weighed.

"Regard" is used in three senses. It can be used when popularity or reputation is a big part of the conclusion reached, as in "He is held in high regard" or "the court regards this as..." (since court opinions are the accumulation of precedents). It can also be used when emotion or sentiment is involved, as in your example where somebody is regarded coldly. The third is the "particular way" that LongMan described.

For your paragraph, I think "considered" would be a better match. Your rule of thumb is good in this case.