# What is the difference between the word 'regard' and 'consider'?

Tags: difference, word-difference

Could you please tell me what is the difference the meaning between the words 'regard' and 'consider',  as used in the sentences below?

> 1. He is **considered** to be a genius.
> 2. He is **regarded** to be a genius.

These sentences are just for example, but I'm often confused with the meaning between 'consider' and 'regard'. Could you please try to eliminate my confusion?

Comment: The words overlap in some meanings. Compare their dictionary definitions.

Answer (score 1):

When used as a verb **regard** means:

> 1. consider or think of (someone or something) in a specified way.

While when used as a verb **consider** means:

> <s>think carefully about (something), typically before making a decision.
>   "each application is considered on its merits"</s>
>
> <s>•think about and be drawn toward (a course of action).
>   "he had considered giving up his job"</s>
>
> •regard (someone or something) as having a specified quality.

They have a lot of overlap in there usage and can be considered synonymous in most situations.

Or as an answer in this post said before: ["Consider" vs. "Regard"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65314/consider-vs-regard)

> **"Consider"** has a general connotation that **logical evidence** is being weighed.
>
> **"Regard"** is used in three senses. It can be used when **popularity** or reputation is a big part of the conclusion reached, as in "He is held in high regard" or "the court regards this as..." (since court opinions are the accumulation of precedents). It can also be used when **emotion or sentiment** is involved, as in your example where somebody is regarded coldly. [<s>The third is the "particular way" that LongMan described.</s>]

Hopefully I made this as clear as possible!